# How to install kerberos client in docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, kerberos, devops

I am trying to create `Docker` image by next `Dockerfile`. It must to install `Kerberos` client.

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:latest

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get -qq update
RUN apt-get -qq install krb5-user libpam-krb5
RUN apt-get -qq clean

COPY / ./

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Next command `RUN apt-get -qq install krb5-user libpam-krb5` from Dockerfile ask me to enter the value to interactive prompt which looks like:

```
Default Kerberos version 5 realm:
```

The point is that the command does not terminate even if I write value and press enter. Whats wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need the `-y` parameter for the apt

```
FROM node:latest

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get -qq update && \
    apt-get -yqq install krb5-user libpam-krb5 && \
    apt-get -yqq clean

COPY / ./

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And pay attention, that each `RUN` directive creates one additional layer in the image. That means, your `clean` command will create a new layer, but all package cache will remain in other layers. So reducing the amount of these directives will be nice. It would help you to shrink the image size.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue and my script was passing in `-y` parameter for apt. The thing I was missing was setting `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`. So it looks like both are needed.

Comment: Is this possible in an alpine version of Node with apk?

Comment: For anyone wanting an explanation of this answer, the "-y" option automatically selects yes on prompts: https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get