# Kerberos Client inside Docker container

Tags: docker, go, kerberos

I have a Go service that requires Kerberos Client (kinit) in order to connect to a Hadoop system.
I that Go service need to be in a container, and I am not allowed to install Kerberos Client on the host machine.
How can I have both Kerberos Client and Go in containers?

Comment: Just install the Kerberos packages in your docker image. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55572477/how-to-install-kerberos-client-in-docker

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install kerberos client in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55572477/how-to-install-kerberos-client-in-docker)

Answer (score 4):

Install `krb5-workstation` in your container. Copy appropriate `krb5.conf` file in `/etc/` directory and in your startup script do **`kinit`** with your KDC **principal** and **keytab**.
***Make sure that KDC server is reachable from your host.***